# Exception thrown when writing an insert function for sLinkedList

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing a "insertBefore" function. I am checking to see if it is firstly the start of the function (This works). I then am trying to have my previous iterator point to the desired location by going through the entire list until its next is equal to the iterator passed into the function (i.e the place I want to insert in front of). 
Now previous is where I want it I am trying to make its next point to the new node (the one I passed into the function) and the new node point to the old iterator after it.

Ive tried swaping the iterators instead.

```
template <typename T, typename InputIterator>
void SLinkedList<T, InputIterator>::insertBefore(InputIterator & t_position, T t_element) 
{
    //Q1

    SListNode<T>* temp = t_position.get();
    SListNode<T>* previous = m_head.get();

    std::unique_ptr<SListNode<T>> newNode = std::make_unique<SListNode<T>>(t_element, this);


    //If position is the head node
    if (t_position.get() == m_head.get())
    {
        insertFirst(t_element);
    }
    else
    {
        while (previous != temp)
        {
            previous = previous->next().get();
        }

        if (previous == temp)
        {
            previous->setNext(newNode);
            newNode->setNext(temp->next());
        }

    }
```

This should insert the new number I passed to insert itself into the list before the iterated position.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], so that everyone can just take the code, compile it and reproduce your problem. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Unrelated: It might be worthwhile for the iterator to keep a reference to the previous node in addition to the node it represents. Make look-up like this simpler.

Comment: `while (previous != temp)` looks like it advances until `previous` IS `temp`, not the node before `temp`. Probably want to rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect

```
previous->setNext(newNode);
```

is causing the issue. `unique_ptr<>` is moveable but not copyable. So, assuming your function `setNext()` did move the `newNode`, calling `newNode->setNext()` is ill formed.

And if you didn't move it (e,g - `const unique_ptr<> &`), then the address is being deleted once the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope (accessing invalid address).

Comment: missing the minimum reproducible example, need to see the setNext implementation for it.

Comment: Then why answer at all? Drop a comment, vote to close and carry on to a question that can be answered. You've picked of one of a few visible bugs. You can't get all the bugs because what is shown suggests that there are a few more fatalities lurking in unposted code.

Comment: I guess you are right. I will keep it in mind next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use a local variable

```
std::unique_ptr<SListNode<T>> newNode;
```

as soon as you go out of scope of `void insertBefore` (end of the function), this `newNode` will get deleted. As such, the whole list will become in an inconsistent state, and if `setNext` moved the value, then `newNode` is invalid after the first line:

```
        previous->setNext(newNode);
        newNode->setNext(temp->next());
```

Comment: Agreed, but with the limited information, it is not quite possible to provide a solution.

Comment: A concrete solution is impossible, but there are a few things that you can suggest, like a smarter constructor for `SListNode` that links the node with it's next, eliminating the need for the second line and then `previous->setNext(std::make_unique<SListNode<T>>(t_element, this, previous->getNext());`. That said, I'm of the opinion this question shouldn't be answered at all. The snippet given suggests the program is broken much worse than this in code that is not shown. You can fix this all you want, but the asker is unlikely benefit from it.